# Tensorflow tfrecords won't allow setting shape?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, training-data

### Situation

I'm trying to store image data in tfrecords.

### Details

The images are have the shape (256,256,4) and the labels (17).  It appears that the tfrecords are saved correctly (height and width attributes can be decoded successfully)

### Issue

An error is thrown when I test out pulling image and labels from the tfrecords using a session.  It appears there is something off with the labels shape

### Error Message

> INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, Input to >reshape is a tensor with 34 values, but the requested shape has 17
>      [[Node: Reshape_4 = Reshape[T=DT_INT32, Tshape=DT_INT32, >_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](DecodeRaw_5, >Reshape_4/shape)]]

### Code

#### *NOTE: I'm pretty confident in this first part as it was copied pretty directly from the tensorflow documation examples*

```
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))

def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

"""Converts a dataset to tfrecords."""
# Open files
train_filename = os.path.join('./data/train.tfrecords')
validation_filename = os.path.join('./data/validation.tfrecords')

# Create writers
train_writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(train_filename)
# validation_writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(validation_filename)

for i in range(200):
    label = y[i]
    img = io.imread(TRAINING_IMAGES_DIR + '/train_' + str(i) + '.tif')

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'width': _int64_feature([img.shape[0]]),
        'height': _int64_feature([img.shape[1]]),
        'channels': _int64_feature([img.shape[2]]),
        'label': _bytes_feature(label.tostring()),
        'image': _bytes_feature(img.tostring())
    }))

#     if i in validation_indices:    
#         validation_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
#     else:
    train_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

train_writer.close()
# validation_writer.close()
```

#### *Error Section.  Note what's especially weird is the fact that if I change the reshape function to [34], I still get the same error.*

```
data_path = './data/train.tfrecords'

with tf.Session() as sess:
    feature = {'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
               'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}

    # Create a list of filenames and pass it to a queue
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1)

    # Define a reader and read the next record
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # Decode the record read by the reader
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)

    # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.float32)

    # Cast label data into int32
    label = tf.decode_raw(features['label'], tf.int8)

    # Reshape image data into the original shape
    image = tf.reshape(image, [256, 256, 4])
    label = tf.reshape(label, [17])

    # Any preprocessing here ...

    # Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors
    images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=1, capacity=20, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=10)

    # Initialize all global and local variables
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)

    # Create a coordinator and run all QueueRunner objects
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    img, lbl = sess.run([images, labels])
    img

    # Stop the threads
    coord.request_stop()

    # Wait for threads to stop
    coord.join(threads)

    sess.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue can arise when your labels were `tf.int16` before it was saved in bytes in the tfrecords. So when you read, as `tf.int8` it has twice the numbers you expect. So you can make sure your labels are written properly by: `label = tf.cast(y[i], tf.int8)` in your tfrecords conversion code.

Comment: I tried casting both the labels and image as np.int32 before saving, and the reading both as tf.int32, but no luck.  I'm still getting `INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, Input to reshape is a tensor with 17 values, but the requested shape has 34
  [[Node: Reshape_12 = Reshape[T=DT_INT32, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](DecodeRaw_13, Reshape_12/shape)]]`

Comment: In that case check the size of `label (= y[i])` and confirm it has 17 values.

Comment: `y[0].shape `  returns `(17,)`  while `img.shape` returns `(256, 256, 4)`

Comment: is it possible that sometimes this shape is not 17?. Can you put a `assert ` when this size is not 17, when you are writing tfrecords?

Comment: Thanks for all these quick follow ups vijay, I added `assert len(label) == 17` to the tfrecrods creation and I received no errors.

Comment: I can debug if you mind sharing the code and a single tfrecord that fails?

Comment: After moving the data and notebook to a new directory, the script suddenly works.  I didn't change anything besides the directory so I'm at a loss.  Still doesn't work in the old directory, but it's fine in the new one.  Thanks for the help Vijay!